# Converting projects from Xcode to Swift Playgrounds on iPad, and vice versa

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

I have a Mac mini (A1347 MD387LL/A) that because of its age is limited to MacOS Catalina. Because of this, it’s limited to running Xcode 12, which is incapable of supporting iOS 15.5, and the App Store now requires that all apps be signed for iOS 15.5.

I also have a 2020 iPad Pro, 12.9", with the latest version of Swift Playgrounds, and it is perfectly capable of submitting apps to the App Store.

Is there any way to convert a project created on my Mac to one that can be opened on the iPad version of Swift Playgrounds?

The only solution that I can think of that might work is to email myself all the files that I modify and do a lot of cutting and pasting. That will get old fast.

Are there any other alternatives that could possibly work? I can’t afford to buy a new Mac at this time.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Whatever solution I use will only be temporary. I plan to buy a new MacBook Air with my tax refund next year.